# How to update document of mongodb using multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a post schema that simply has attributes like _id, text, likes and comments. I want to push user id into likes array it if fulfills two conditions. Firstly the id of the post should match the query param and then the likes array should not already contain the id of the person trying to like the post. Instead error msg should come: Post already liked.

Like key pair from post schema

```
likes:[{
    user:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath:'onModel'
    }        
}]
```

I wrote the following query but it doesn't work. The update part works fine but some issue with the first argument.

```
Post.update({$and: [{ _id: req.params.postid},{"likes": { $ne : { user: 
authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id  }}}]},
            { $push: { likes: {user: authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }}})
            .then(post => res.json(post))
            .catch(err => res.json(err))
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: what does it mean "it doesn't work"?  what is "some issue"?  are you getting an error? or more likely are you getting nothing updated but you don't know if it's because there is no matching user or if the likes array already has this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it can be simple in this way :

```
Post.update({
    _id: req.params.postid,
    'likes.user': {
        $ne:
            authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id
    }
},
    { $push: { likes: { user: authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id } } })
    .then(post => res.json(post))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
```

Comment: Yes it works but a slight problem appears i.e  though the user is not being added in the array but still the 'then' block executes. It does not run the catch block.

Comment: @Emma : `.then()` & `.catch()` are executing properly, if a DB operation doesn't fail then it will go to `.then()`, whether we added user or not it's not a failure, an update operation to DB is successfully triggered but since the condition is not met it won't update document - it's not a failure as you didn't get an actual error from DB !! `.catch()` gets executed when there is any failures in DB calls like DB connectivity/Errors in query Etc.. You need to write a condition for post in `.then()` to check if any doc updated if yes then send final result accordingly..